# Can these tags be created?

Tags: support, tags

Several tag suggestions:

- demonology
- 2-john
- 3-john
- haggai
- baruch

Comment: Tags cannot be created without questions to attach them to. Anybody with enough rep can edit these into questions where they are appropriate, but they can't just hang there with no content.

Answer (score 2):

I proposed demonology as a synonym for demons:

> [Tag synonyms for **Demon**](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tags/demons/synonyms)

The rest can be made when someone actually asks a question about those books.  If you can find two questions that are directly asking about those books, please link to 'em and we'll tag them (if there are only one question for each book, then it's not really worth it to re-tag since the tag could get deleted by the tag deleting robot)

Another suggestion would be [minor-prophets](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minor-prophets) although that might be a tad too meta for a useful tag.

Comment: minor-prophets would be good if there are questions about the 12 as a whole... and there might be, I haven't checked haha

Comment: @curiousdannii I suspect that would simply be synonymised with [prophets](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prophets).